# How can I use derived class when inherite from an interface

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I tried to create my DbContext like this:

```
public interface IMyDbContext
{
    IQueryable<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
public class MyDbContext: DbContext, IMyDbContext
{
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

I don't want to use `IDbSet` in the interface because that class is used in another projects which does not use EntityFramework.

Visual Studio said that `MyDbContext` does not implement the member `IQueryable<Product>`, but `DbSet<Product>` is derived from `IQueryable<Product>`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696460(v=vs.113).aspx

Could you please tell me why? And how can I fix this issue?

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Edit with code demonstrating how you're calling this.

Comment: @Jannik: IQueryable<T> is under System.Linq, not EF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interface implementation has to exactly match the interface definition. So you can't have a property typed as `IQueryable<T>` on the interface and implement it with property typed as `DbSet<T>` on the class.

Use [explicit interface implementation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx) to work around that:

```
public interface IMyDbContext
{
    IQueryable<Product> Products { get; }
}

public class MyDbContext: DbContext, IMyDbContext
{
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    IQueryable<Product> IMyDbContext.Products { get { return Products; } }
}
```

As you can see, I removed the setter from the interface. That's because otherwise you'd need extra type checks, because there is plenty of classes that implement `IQueryable<Product>` but can't be assigned to `DbSet<Product>`.

Comment: Out of curiosity: A setter wouldn't make any sense in this case, would it? :)

Comment: Thank you, I got it. But in my opinion, explicit implementation is ugly and would not be recommended, isnt it?

Comment: It doesn't have to be explicit, you can just change the `DbSet<Product>` property name to something different than `Products`.